# Encrypting text using Python - RaspberryPi Org projects

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, raspberry-pi3

I'm doing this 'project' on the official raspberry pi site where I learn to encrypt messages using Python.

I'm following the 'Secret Agent Chat' project, and at [step 8](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/secret-agent-chat/8) I encountered a problem. I double checked all the lines I wrote, and I'm pretty sure I did it exactly as the project told me to do it. So either I still did something wrong after double checking everything I wrote, or the project is not right. 
If it turns out to be a fault in the project, I will report it. But I guess the chance is higher I did something wrong, so I hope you can help me find it.

The problem I experience is, when I execute the program I wrote (I try to encrypt a message), I dont get a full encrypted message. I literally just get the first letter of the message back I tried to encrypt. Example:

```
>>> sheet = load_sheet('otp0.txt')
>>> encrypt ('Hualiwei.', sheet)
'H'
>>>
```

I should get something like this:

```
>>> sheet = load_sheet('otp0.txt')
>>> encrypt ('Hualiwei.', sheet)
'Keudnsqn.'
>>>
```

Below here, I put the code that I wrote for the project. It should be exactly the same as shown in the project.

```
from random import randint
ALPHABET = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
def generate_otp(sheets, length):
    for sheet in range(sheets):
        with open("otp" + str(sheet) + ".txt","w") as f:
            for i in range(length):
                f.write(str(randint(0,26))+"\n")
def load_sheet(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        contents = f.read().splitlines()
    return contents
def get_plain_text():
    plain_text = input('Please type your message ')
    return plain_text.lower()
def load_file(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        contents = f.read()
    return contents
def save_file(filename, data):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(data)
def encrypt(plaintext, sheet):
    ciphertext = ''
    for position, character in enumerate(plaintext):
        if character not in ALPHABET:
            ciphertext += character
        else:
            encrypted = (ALPHABET.index(character) + int(sheet[position])) % 26
            ciphertext += ALPHABET[encrypted]
        return ciphertext
```

I really wonder what I'm doing wrong. I hope you can help me, and by doing so, help alot of other people who might be experiencing the same problem which is putting them off on experimenting with these Raspberry Pi projects(if the problem is not on my part, at least).

Thanks alot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your return statement in the encryption function indented too much? I haven't run the code but after a quick look it does look like this could return only one letter without running through all of them.

Comment: God damn it, you're right... I feel like I keep making such mistakes, so frustrating.. Do you have any hints or pro tips for me to avoid making such mistakes or spot them easier?

Comment: Perhaps including some print statements in the code would have helped you find the issue. For example printing out the ciphertext string each time a new letter is added to it.